# Django timezone error

Tags: django, windows

I'm a newbie in Django, and I' doing the official tutorial( https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/tutorial02/ ). I reached the part of the tutorial where I have to add the 'was_published_recently' object to the admin site. I get the following error when I try to add:

```
Exception Type:     NameError Exception Value:  

global name 'timezone' is not defined

Exception Location:     in was_published_recently, line 9 Python
Executable:     c:\python27\python.exe Python Version:  2.7.4 Python
Path: 

['E:\\Egyetem\\programoz\xe1s\\webfejleszt\xe9s a gyakorlatban\\Django
projects\\first project\\mysite', 
'C:\\Windows\\system32\\python27.zip',  
'c:\\python27\\DLLs', 
'c:\\python27\\lib',  
'c:\\python27\\lib\\plat-win', 
'c:\\python27\\lib\\lib-tk',  
'c:\\python27', 
'c:\\python27\\lib\\site-packages']
```

I've tried to add to the enviromental path c:\python27\lib but it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: It sounds like you have an older version of Django installed. How did you install it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tutorial 2 refers back to tutorial 1, where this is mentioned:

```
from django.utils import timezone
```

Add that to your script.

Comment: I added this line to my models.py file and also this line:
import datetime
     Thank you, now it works :)